# Two events at the same time

Tags: jquery

I want to do some actions when class .smth is clicked

```
$('.smth').click(function() {
```

and when key is pressed:

```
$('.txt').bind('keypress', function(e) {
```

I want to do the same action, so how can I use them both with OR or something like that?

```
$('.log').click.or.$('.txt').bind('keypress', function(e) {
```

?

THank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If this was the same collection of elements you could use:

```
$(".myclass").bind("click keypress", function(event) {
    //...
});
```

But as it's different elements you'll have to follow Felix advice and write a function then attach it as the event handler.

Comment: but I can do `$(".input_class, .button_class").bind("click keypress", function(event) {`

Comment: It will bind both events too all elements, thought you want different event for each set of element. If that's really what you want then glad I could guide you in the correct direction. :)

Answer (score 9):

Use a named function instead of an anonymous one.

```
function handler() {
    //...
}

$('.txt').keypress(handler);
$('.smth').click(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle multiple things in one event have a look on this

```
$(".smth, .txt, .log").bind("click keypress", function(event) {
    console.log("key pressed");
});
```