# Observer events in JS Prototype - two events at the same time

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, observer-pattern

I have an input box that takes a number that gets verified in function opConfig.reloadPrice(). I set 2 observers one the same element, on 'change' it executes the code when I click outside the box or use tab-if the change has been made. On 'keypress' it checks if the return key was pressed then executes the code **AND** it also triggers the 'change' observer!! So in this case the function opConfig.reloadPrice()  gets executed twice (and I end up with two identical alert boxes).
The code that I have now:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[1]" id="options_1" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)">

Event.observe($('options_1'), 'change', function(e){ 
   opConfig.reloadPrice(); 
}); 
Event.observe($('options_1'),'keypress', function(e){ 
  if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN)  
    opConfig.reloadPrice(); 
});
```

I've tried several different solutions (I've tried 'blur' event, putting one observer in the other... )
I'm looking for a solution similar to this one 
*[jQuery-Two events at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581088/two-events-at-the-same-time)*

Thanks a million

EDIT-Solved:
Thanks to **katspaugh** I solved this. There were few things that were not clear to me, one of them is:  'keypress' event is observed *before* 'change' event, which is why you can set variables in one observer and check them later in another (this is also why it took me a while to understand katspaughs code :-)  ).
Anyway, I change the code a bit that it suits me:

```
var enterPressed = 0;  

Event.observe($('options_1'), 'change', function(){ 
  if (enterPressed !== 1) {    
    opConfig.reloadPrice();  
  }
  enterPressed = 0;
  });

Event.observe($('options_1'), 'keypress', function(e){  
if ((e.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) || (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_TAB)) {
  enterPressed = 1;
  opConfig.reloadPrice();   
}
else 
  enterPressed = 0;  
});
```

Cheers,
jazkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current value of the input field in an upper-scope variable (up-value).

If the value changes in one of the events, fire the handler and update the upvalue:

```
var oldVal;

$('options_1').observe(
  'change', function () {
      var val = this.value;
      if (oldVal !== val) {
          oldVal = val;
          opConfig.reloadPrice();
      }
  }
).observe(
    'keypress', function(e) { 
        oldVal = this.value;
        if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
            opConfig.reloadPrice();
        }
    }
);
```

Also, you'd better remove the inline listener in HTML (and **never** add them again):

```
<input type="text" name="options[1]" id="options_1" />
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozurec).

Comment: Thanks katspaugh for such a quick respond, however it's still executing twice when change has been made and return key is pressed:
change + tab   = OK,
change + click out   = OK,
change + enter   = executes twice  (not OK)

Comment: I tweaked it to a working example, but you should understand the general idea: a shared variable that you check/update in each handler.

Comment: Yep, and I appreciate it, but it's still giving me the same issue which I'm trying to get rid of - when value is changed and return key is clicked the function is executed twice (and thus giving me 2 pop-ups). I can't think of any good solution to prevent that... :-/

Comment: Strange. What browser do you check it in? In Chrome it alerts only once in my demo (http://jsbin.com/ozurec).

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6 and FF 5.0 - same result.

Comment: If I try in IE8 then when changing and pressing enter function executes once - which is good. Let me try Chrome and Safari. Yep fine here as well. Hm, so only FF is acting this way...

Comment: My Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 6 execute `checkLength` once. Try checking http://jsbin.com/ozurec/2 — it has `alert` replaced with something less annoying and keeping the input field focused.

Comment: Hm, it still isn't working... If I test your code in JS Bin then it's fine in every browser, so I guess there is something else in my code that's triggering function twice... And my client is dead set on pop box :-)  though I like your second solution... Will check the rest of the code and let you know how I'm doing. Thanks for now!!

Comment: It's okay, glad you figured it out!